# How to use SDL locally in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, sdl, sdl-image

I want to add SDL and SDL_image to my Visual Studio project. But can I do it locally only for this project? I don't want to put the dlls in System32 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by *Ciprian Khlud*, you could simply put your DLLs next to the output binary (.exe). You could find output directory in

```
Right click on project -> Project Settings -> General -> Output Directory
```

Alternatively, you could add the folder where DLLs are into the list of search directories:

```
Right click on project -> Project Settings -> VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories
```

(same way as you add include dirs and library dirs)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to copy them either manually into your output folder or to create a post build event.

Use Microsoft link to see where you can put your Dlls without conflicting with System32:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx